# How to call config.xml for msbuild script

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, build-process, configuration-files

**My Goal**

I need to have `config.xml` file for each build script.

**My Question**

How do I call/reference that `.xml` file to MSBuild script. `<import>` task doesn't work for that.

**Note** I am new to MSBuild script, using it for automating all our builds.

Comment: What is `config.xml`, and how do you use it currently?

Comment: basically it will be holding all the core values. which i want to use through script. msbuild script should call this file. like we <import> project for all the task. it will actually hold properties/values/ for the build script. so if theres a change i just need to change that config file. hope this gives a clear idea what i am looking for.

Comment: how can msbuild read .xml file? msbuild script should be able to use values/attributes from that .xml file. i think this make sense. sorry for my not so correct question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link below may assist you:
[msbuild XML tutorial](http://thomasardal.com/msbuild-tutorial/)

Let me know if that helps you...

**update**
You can use msbuild extension pack to read XML with msbuild, read about it here:

https://msbuildextensionpack.codeplex.com/discussions/244051

Download it from here:

http://www.msbuildextensionpack.com/

Comment: Thanks DeJaVo. but my actual question is "
 
how can msbuild read .xml file? msbuild script should be able to use values/attributes from that .xml file." i think this make sense. sorry for my not so correct question

Answer (score 0):

I import a file with a PropertyGroup defined on it, and the PropertyGroup contains the settings I need configurable.